# to disable JULI logs in tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat

I recently faced an issue where the JULI logs in Catalina_home directory started growing hugely at rapid pace in PROD environment. 
I tried to change the logging levels to 'OFF' in logging.properties file but that didn't help, hence I removed the below line from Java options of Tomcat manager wizard.
 `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager` 

 Now the JULI logs are not created. I am not sure if this is the optimum approach. I would like to know the impact of removing the above line. 
If there are any other best approach to resolve the issue, then kindly share. 
**Note:** My application uses Log4j for logging purpose and not JULI jars.

Comment: You may modify default logging options by adding something like "maxDays" to have logs deleted after N number of days. Here is example: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: @kosa to manually delete a JULI log we have to stop the tomcat instance then delete. When we use maxDays parameter, say if I use maxDays = 2, so for every 2 days tomcat will restart itself to delete the logs ?